# Steps for adding android annotations to Android studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio, build.gradle, android-annotations

I am following this link to add Android Annotations to android studio : http://www.jayway.com/2014/12/19/androidannotations-setup-android-studio/

I am not sure why my new build.gradle (the first code) is not working (throwing numerous errors like R.android - basically the resources not being found). It stems from my lack of understand of the gradle scripting language

#### The current build.grade in my app folder is as below:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.2'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}


apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.earthmileslftr.earthmiles'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.apptentive:apptentive-android:1.6.+@aar'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.talenguyen:prettysharedpreferences:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.5@aar'
    compile project(':facebook')
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
```

#### The previous build.gradle that was working perfectly is as below

```
apply plugin: 'android'

    android {
        signingConfigs {
            debug {
            }
        }
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
            debug {
                debuggable true
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.apptentive:apptentive-android:1.6.+@aar'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
        compile 'com.github.talenguyen:prettysharedpreferences:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
        compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.0.0@aar'
        compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
        compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.5@aar'
        compile project(':facebook')
    }
```

#### The errors I get are as follows

```
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/AuthorizationClient.java
Error:(29, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/FacebookRequestError.java
Error:(19, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java
Error:(40, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/LoginActivity.java
Error:(24, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/Settings.java
Error:(33, 28) error: cannot find symbol class BuildConfig
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal/ImageDownloader.java
Error:(25, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/FriendPickerFragment.java
Error:(29, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/GraphObjectAdapter.java
Error:(27, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/LikeView.java
Error:(35, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/PlacePickerFragment.java
Error:(36, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/RequestBatch.java
Error:(175, 8) error: self-closing element not allowed
Error:(195, 8) error: self-closing element not allowed
/Users/somghosh/volt-android/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal/ImageRequest.java
Warning:(31, 12) no description for @param
```

Comment: "throwing numerous errors" is not a useful problem description unless you include the information regarding what "errors" are being "thrown". If you're not sure why, call your doctor and say "I don't feel well. My body hurts in various places. What's wrong?" and see if you get a diagnosis and treatment plan without providing a lot more detail.

Comment: Your build.gradle seems to be okay. Just one thing i noticed: where do you declare the android plugin dep? Also the name `android` is deprecated, you should use `com.android.application.` I suggest to try out our [example project](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/tree/develop/examples/gradle) to see whether that compiles.

Comment: Did you get that solved?

Answer (score 1):

In the project build.gradle file you can add the following code:

```
if (JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()) {
    allprojects {
        tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
            options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you are disabling new option in Java8 JavaDoc tool.

Special thanks to the Stephen Colebourne from blog:
http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html

Comment: This works fine and solve for me the issue with `self-closing element not allowed` gradle error.